# Download contents of POST request to file

Tags: brightscript

I'm working on a Roku app that displays MJPEG videos.  This is a little bit tricky because as far as I can tell there isn't really a way to handle a generic stream over HTTP in Brightscript.  What I've done that works is initiate a download with roUrlTransfer.GetToFile.  I can then process the tmp file that is created as the MJPEG is continuously downloaded.  I have to clean up the file and restart the transfer every once in awhile to avoid overflowing the storage space, but it works well enough.

The problem I'm having is that one of the sources I need to support requires that I POST some session information in order to pull down the MJPEG I need to display.  As far as I can tell roUrlTransfer doesn't provide a way to POST a string and save the result as a file.  Is there a way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

I nice workaround for this issue is to set url as normal **GET** request (params in query string) and overwrite request method to **POST**. Then you can use *GetToString()* to return the request data. See example below:

```
conn = CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
url = "http://somedomain.com/endpoint?param1=foo&param2=bar"
conn.SetUrl(url)
conn.SetRequest("POST")    'do not forget to overwrite http method
data = conn.GetToString()
```

**Edit:** I just realised that my response does not answer your question. Anyway, I wont delete it because it may be the answer for others fellows.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to ask this is Developer forum at forums.roku.com

I believe i heard to get the body from a post you have to use the async version of post, 
http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ifUrlTransfer#ifUrlTransfer-AsyncPostFromStringrequestasStringasBoolean

You will be getting `roUrlEvent`s as the call progresses and may not even have to save MJPEG to tmp: to handle it (can slice and dice in memory. tmp: is RAM drive anyway)

Comment: According to the documentation you get an roUrlEvent when the request completes (which this one never will) not as the call progresses.  The roUrlEvent documentation also lists two event types: started and completed.  Does it actually send back events as the call progresses?  I'd be thrilled if the documentation were wrong here.  As far as the forums I signed up to post this there as well yesterday and still haven't received my account confirmation email.

Comment: Why not try and see? Docs are not always right. I imagine you'd be getting `roUrlEvent` for every http chunk, at least. Surprised you cannot post before email verification, i'll PM moderator there re your ID.

Comment: Thank you for PMing the moderator, he took care of my forum access for me.  I tried with AsyncGetToString and there are no chunks that come back.  Since the request never completes no roUrlEvent comes back.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the only way to do this is to use ifUrlTransfer.AsyncPostFromFiletoFile(sourcefile,DestFile) and then you can read the response body from the file system. If the download is a media file, you should make sure it has the correct extension as Roku tends to decide what media type is what based on the extension.